# Dropdown menu text starting from right to left in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, dropdown

[image: screenshot]

I'm currently working on a website with a dropdown menu, but I'm facing an issue where the text in the dropdown menu is starting from right to left instead of the expected left to right. I've tried using the `direction: ltr;` property, but nothing changed / it doesn't seem to be working. I would appreciate some assistance in resolving this issue.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Treatments</a>
      <ul class="dropDownMenuIndex">
        <li><a href="#">Visit our Studio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mobile Massages</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="book" href="bookNow.html">Book Now</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And my CSS code:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  --navload-time: 300ms;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: right;
  animation: navload 300ms ease-in;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

a:hover {
  color: #46c577;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul li ul.dropDownMenuIndex li {
  display: block;
  unicode-bidi: normal;
}

ul li ul.dropDownMenuIndex {
  width: 1650px;
  background: #46c577;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  color: #fff; /* Set the text color to white */
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #59cc59;
}

ul li:hover ul.dropDownMenuIndex {
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover > a {
  background: #ffff33;
}

ul li:hover ul.dropDownMenuIndex {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: you set `text-align: right;` change it to `text-align: left;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your nav has set `text-align: right;` so dropDownMenuIndex class will inherit its parent.
just set the dropDownMenuIndex text-align as left

```
ul li ul.dropDownMenuIndex li {
  text-align: left;
}
```